# Hosted Zone and Amplify AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-route53, aws-route53

I have set up a hosted zone in AWS with Route 53 as public zone. But my site shows server not found.

I filled in the Nameservers in the config at my provider. I checked that with https://www.whatsmydns.net/ the nameservers are found correctly.
Then I set up the Domain for my App in Amplify under Domain management. It also says Status: Available. When I open the domain now, it asks for the password that I set up under Access Control in Amplify. After I entered this, the page shows server not found. I waited more than 72h between both steps. Stil no change.
What could be wrong?

Edit:
found the problem, AWS created some redirect entries with the domain as source and target and type 302. After removing these entries it works.